# Convert Array in another format

Tags: php, laravel

So i have this array of countries,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [AF] => Afghanistan
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [AX] => Ã…land Islands
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [AL] => Albania
    )
)
```

I want to convert in into the below format of key value pair :

```
Array(['AF'] => 'Afghanisthan' , ['AX'] => 'A...land', ['AL'] => 'Albania');
```

Thanks

Comment: Loop through the array then assign it to another array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$newArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $oldArray);
```

`call_user_func_array` goes through all items in `$oldArray` and merges them with `array_merge` into `$newArray`.

See working <kbd>[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e04855a063660a38731a2b49179b0159fc677186)</kbd>